# adding javascript variables to session attributes using jsp

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, variables

i have to add java script variable time(var time=date.getTime())  to session? is it possible to convert java script variable to java variable?

Comment: Well you can make an ajax call and then in the server side you can access the HttpSession and save it there. Although if you are just saving current time, you can easily do that in java based on LOCALE instead of passing the time from a js.

Comment: why not create a cookie with the variable in it.  It will be accessible to the back and front end in that case.  if you only need it for a short time the backend can remove the cookie once its picked the value up.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this directly because JS is client side & Java servlets (JSP pages) are running on server side. You must send your JS variables to server (e.g. using AJAX requests) & then handle sent values in a java servlet.